# How to mark a known self-signed server as trusted for wget

Tags: networking, ssl, https, ubuntu-12.04, wget

Im trying to use wget to download content over https from a self-signed ubuntu host in our LAN. of course wget doesnt allow that, and in all the answers I've found they promoted using the: --no-check-certificate, this will expose me to "man in the middle" attacks. since I know the destination host, and have access to its certs is there a way to add the host to a "trusted" list, so that its certificate will be validated against a local copy?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the --ca-certificate parameter.

Comment: thanks! i dont know how i missed that